# Why do some items have the Saints logo next to them?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

When customizing my character's outfit or selecting a vehicle, why do some items have the Third Street Saints logo next to them?

[image: Clothing items with Saints logo]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're DLC items. Maybe you've got them as a preorder bonus:

> If Saints Row: The Third was pre-ordered, this DLC was added for free.

For example:

- **Battalion Pants** are from [Explosive Combat Pack](https://saintsrow.fandom.com/wiki/Explosive_Combat_Pack).
- **Reality Climax Pants** are from [Funtime! pack](https://saintsrow.fandom.com/wiki/Funtime!_Pack).
- **Space Princess Tights** are from [Warrior pack](https://saintsrow.fandom.com/wiki/Warrior_Pack).
- **Witch Pants** are from [Witches and Wieners pack](https://saintsrow.fandom.com/wiki/Witches_and_Wieners).

And some of them also include vehicles.

Comment: I have most of the DLC, so this makes sense!